# Mongo select distinct on multiple fields + generic architecture

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently learning MongoDB and I have a few problems.

For a project, I was using SQL and I had 3 tables: Artist, Album, Song.

Then I decided to change to Mongo as I have a lot of rows and also because I was curious...

In Mongo, I have only one collection Song with everything in it:

- trackName
- artistName
- artwork
- folder
- albumName
- albumDate

First I would like to know if this structure is correct or if I should create on collection for each table that I had in SQL?
My main objective is to be able to search for artistName="something" and trackName="something_else"... With a simple find it works really fast! :)

However I also need a page to display all the artists with their link (folder), and here's my problem:
I want to show all the artists, order by artistName, starting with A (for example) and get the folder for each artist...

I tried this:

```
$cursor =$collection->distinct("artistName", array( "artistName" => $regex));
```

that works fine, but I need the `folder`..

Then I tried this:

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "artistName" => 1,
            "folder"   => 1,
        )
    ),
    array('$match' => array( "artistName" => $regex)),
    array('$group' => array(
                        '_id'=>'$artistName',
                        "artistName" => array('$first' => '$artistName'),
                        "folder" => array('$first' => '$folder')
                        ),
    array('$sort' => array('artistName'=>-1)),
    )
);

$results = $collection->aggregate($ops);
```

That works without the sort but with the sort I have the following error:

```
Pipeline::run(): unrecognized pipeline op "0'
```

So my question is what's the best way to do what I need?

Thanks a lot,
Valentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is good, in this case the simplicity is a good thing.you can check the tutorial how to design dm in mongodb [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/). For the proposal that you wrote i would choose aggregation framework and in the syntax that you wrote there is an error that  caused the problem, you wrote the $sort inside the $groups array's bracket. try this:

```
$ops = array(
    array('$project' => array(
                          "artistName" => 1,
                          "folder"   => 1,
                          )
         ),
    array('$match' => array( "artistName" => $regex)),
    array('$group' => array(
                        '_id'=>'$artistName',
                        "artistName" => array('$first' => '$artistName'),
                        "folder" => array('$first' => '$folder')
                        )
         ),
    array('$sort' => array('artistName'=>-1))
    );
```

There is also a little conceptional error in it. Due to the relation is many to many i guess between the folder and the artist that structure only will give you the first folder where the artist match. also the "artistName" => array('$first' => '$artistName'), whit this i guess you were liked to have another field which contains the artistName, it is the same with the _id. In the group operators array the _id related to the key of the gourping function as the GROUP BY field in SQL. You can check the operation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group).

For your case i would use:

```
$ops = array(
    array('$match' => array( "artistName" => $regex)),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "artistName" => 1,
            "folder"   => 1,
        )
    ),
    array('$group' => array(
                        '_id'=>array('artistName' => '$artistName', 
                                     'folder' => '$folder')
                        )),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "_id" => 0,
            "artistName" => '$_id.artistName',
            "folder"   => '$_id.folder',
        )
    ),
    array('$sort' => array('artistName'=>-1))
);
```

Comment: Thank you really much! I will test tonight but this should great!
About the artist and folder, actually in my system, I have one unique folder by artist and the folder is like a key for the artist... So I don't know if this match with your answer so I will check tonight...
Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: I just checked your solutions and both are working in my case! ;)
Solved! :D